# How to set cookie for domain?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

A cookie is set when using localhost but it's not set in a domain.

```
 Cookie c2 = new Cookie("icart",sessionCart.countItem()); 
 c2.setMaxAge(500000);
 httpServletResponse.addCookie(c2)
```

The above code works fine in localhost ,it sets cookie

the below i tried after hosting my project online but not working

```
Cookie c3 = new Cookie("icart",sessionCart.countItem());        
c3.setDomain("sreeanandham.com");
c3.setMaxAge(500000);
httpServletResponse.addCookie(c3);    
return sessionCart.countItem();
```

Comment: do you have any more information as to why this is happening/what you are doing when you are running into an issue? You must be setting the cookie right if it loads on localhost, but I don't have enough info to trace your issue. Are you using `setDomain()` as you have shown and actually visiting the domain `sreeanandham.com`? My initial thought is that you are attempting to gather the cookie from the set domain in localhost, but this would not be possible as the cookie would only be delivered to requests from the set domain. https://www.baeldung.com/java-servlet-cookies-session

Comment: Alternatively, and out of curiosity, why are you setting the domain? If you do not pass that method, the visited site (whether localhost or on a web host), would have the appropriate cookie set when a user visits your site. All that matters at that point is where you actually publish your files, you would not hard code the domain in your project.

Comment: when i work in localhost , i dont give setDomain or setPath ,it works fine ,when i hosting my project online , it didnt set cookie on browser , so i put setDomain("mydomain") but nothing works , please help ,today fully im doing this only